# Передача структурированных данных через сокет

Tags: java, сокет

Здравствуйте. Написал чат на сокетах. Все хорошо работает. Там вся передача основана на строчках. Вопрос такой, можно ли на Java передавать объекты или массивы с помощью сокета?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Распространенный подход - это сериализация данных в текстовое представление на передающей стороне и десериализация - на принимающей. В качестве формата можно выбрать XML, JSON, BSON и т.п.

```
class Sample {
  private int value = 0;
  Sample() {
  }
}

// Сериализация
Sample sample = new Sample();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(sample);

// json содержит {"value":0}

// Десериализация
Sample sample = gson.fromJson(json, Sample.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

В Java есть встроенные обертки на бинарные потоки ввода-вывода - ObjectInputStream и ObjectOutputStream. Возможно, они вам помогут.